# TabBar to view and when closed come back to previous selected view

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, ios10

I'm developing an iOS app with swift in which I have a TabBarController with 5 tab bar items. All of them points to a navigation controller and then to a view controller. One of them I want to show a view controller without the tab bar and when the user press cancel it should go back to the previous tab bar item/view that was selected (previously - sorry for the redundancy). They are all linked/referenced by a "Relationship "view controllers" to "name of the view", but I don't have any specific segue or whatsoever.

This is the code for that specific "button" which I call in the **viewDidLoad** function:

```
func setupMiddleButton() {
    let menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 64))
    var menuButtonFrame = menuButton.frame
    menuButtonFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height
    menuButtonFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.width/2 - menuButtonFrame.size.width/2
    menuButton.frame = menuButtonFrame

    menuButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    menuButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButtonFrame.height/2

    menuButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "klein_fototoestel_2"), for: UIControlState.normal) // 450 x 450px
    menuButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuButtonAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(menuButton)


    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func menuButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    self.selectedIndex = 2
}
```

I tried to perform the behaviour I want by delegating the tab bar controller with the following code **but** this function is never called when the central button is selected (though the correct view shows up..!):

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

    print("the selected index is : \(tabBar.items?.index(of: item))")
}
```

What I really want to know is what is the correct way to implement that behaviour I want. Remembering that all views have a navigationController before. I read a lot of people suggesting using UserDefaults to store the index of the previous controller but to be honest I really don't think that's appropriate.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hmmm.... you have a tab bar, with 5 tabs? Tabs 1, 2, 4, 5 each are associated with a view controller... but tab button 3 you want to show a view that *covers* the tabbar itself? and then a button inside that view removes the view and returns you to whichever tab was active? Does that sound right?

Comment: and... `setupMiddleButton()` and `menuButtonAction()` are both in a subclassed tab bar controller? and... `menuButtonAction()` *is* being called on button tap?

Comment: Hey Don. Exactly! Thanks in advance!

Comment: ok - without digging any further, it *looks* like the easiest route would be to load your "special" view controller and show it with `presentViewController()` right from `menuButtonAction()`. That way, when you dismiss it, you will never have left the tab you were looking at.

Comment: Ah, Don, I kinda tried to do that but it complained that the view was already loaded (sorry I don't remember the error message) and I couldn't instantiate it or even refer to it (through self.tabcontroller.viewcontroller[2] for example)

Comment: Looks like you were on the right track... see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were on the right track - just need to get the correct connections.

In this diagram (it's kinda big - easier to read if you open it in a new tab), you see a "standard" UITabBar structure. The key is putting a default "do-nothing" view controller as the 3rd tab, and then adding a "special" view controller which will be loaded via code:

[image]

Then, your "action" function will look something like this:

```
func menuButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

    // Don't navigate to the tab index
    //self.selectedIndex = 2

    // instead, load and present the view you really want to see

    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SpecialVC") as? SpecialViewController {

        vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext

        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

You can see and download a working example here: https://github.com/DonMag/SWTabsWithSpecialTab

Comment: Awesome, Don. Thank you very much.